# Checking PhoneGap version in xCode

Tags: xcode, cordova, version

I have a problem with my phonegap-based project, and I'm suspecting I'm running a different version than I think. the config.xml file I'm using states it's 2.0.0, while I thought it's 2.9.

Is there a way to actually check the phonegap version in xcode, and not relay on a comment in a single file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I would add to @user1279357's answer, which demonstrates how to acquire the version of Cordova from the JavaScript side. However, on the Objective-C side, if you add `#import <Cordova/CDVAvailability.h>` you can call the constant: `CORDOVA_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED`.

This constant is an `int` that will provide you with the version of Cordova you are using. The value is in the form of: 20000 = 2.0, 20800 = 2.8 e.t.c.

If you need to do checks against this value, there are other constants defined in this file for each of the versions, e.g. `__CORDOVA_2_0_0` = 2.0.

Look [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVAvailability.h) to see the source file for `CDVAvailability.h`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use device object's cordova(device.cordova) property to get the version of phonegap.
Below link provides more information for same.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device

Answer (score 0):

Look in your cordova.js file at the top in the comments.

If you're using a really old version of cordova, it will be in the listed in the filename like "Cordova2.7.js"